# SignalR Client error when trying to connect to server with connection.Start()

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I'm using the stocks SignalR example from ASP.NET website:

```
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20
```

The server is running fine and the JavaScript clients are working as they are supposed to and communicating between one another. The server and JavaScript client are running on IIS.

The JavaScript client is at:

```
http://192.168.1.5:8080/RTStreamer/SignalR.Sample/StockTicker.html
```

Now I'm trying to do a C# Windows Forms client but without success:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connection = new HubConnection("http://192.168.1.5:8080/RTStreamer/signalr");
    IHubProxy proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("StockTickerHub");

    try
    {
        connection.Start().Wait();
        var stocks = proxy.Invoke<IEnumerable<Stock>>("GetAllStocks").Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error when trying the connection.Start():

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 13:46:31 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Get>b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass19`2.<Then>b__17(Task`1 t)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass3a.<RunTask>b__39(Task`1 t)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at TraderClient.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Ark\Form1.cs:line 31
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 13:46:31 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Get>b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass19`2.<Then>b__17(Task`1 t)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass3a.<RunTask>b__39(Task`1 t)<---
```

This is the Hub code:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StockTicker
{
    [HubName("stockTicker")]
    public class StockTickerHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly StockTicker _stockTicker;

        public StockTickerHub()
            : this(StockTicker.Instance)
        {

        }

        public StockTickerHub(StockTicker stockTicker)
        {
            _stockTicker = stockTicker;
        }

        public IEnumerable<StockQuote> GetAllStocks()
        {
            return _stockTicker.GetAllStocks();
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Having set the project up exactly as per the linked article, the .NET client that works for me has the following code:

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:65069/");
IHubProxy proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("stockTickerMini");

try
{
    connection.Start().Wait();
    var stocks = proxy.Invoke<IEnumerable<Stock>>("GetAllStocks").Result;
}
...
```

In my example, the `StockTicker.html` page is at `http://localhost:65069/StockTicker.html` and the hub name is `stockTickerMini` as per the attribute.

In your case then the values below should be right:

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://192.168.1.5:8080/RTStreamer");
IHubProxy proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("stockTicker");
```

Comment: Checked the endpoint connection and the site is: http://192.168.1.5:8080/RTStreamer/signalr/abort?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=....

Comment: One other note: to match the right version of the SignalR stuff that is installed by the template actions in the article, I got the got the 2.0.2 version of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client from nuget, not the latest version. (don't think it'll matter, but didn't want the extra variable in the test)